# Expectation of Conditional expectation over incorrect distribution

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

We want to compute the following quantity
\begin{align}
\int E[V|W=u] f_U(u) du
\end{align}
For random variables $ V,W,U$  where $V$ and $U$ are independent and $U$ is absolutely continuous r.v.

Is the following chain of equalities correct
\begin{align}
\int E[V|W=u] f_U(u) du = E_U[ E_{V|W}[V|W] ]=E_V[V] 
\end{align}

Also, this problem well defined?

Comment: The integral is $E(g(U))$ where $g$ is such that $E(V\mid W)=g(W)$ almost surely. Unless $W$ and $U$ follow the same distribution, there is no reason why the identity $E(g(U))=E(V)$ should hold since $E(V)=E(g(W))$, not $E(g(U))$. Note that the independence of $U$ and $V$ is irrelevant. On the contrary, if $V$ and $W$ are independent then the function $g(\ )$ is constant and equal to $E(V)$ hence $E(g(U))=E(V)$ holds for any $U$.

Comment: @Did Thanks. You're awesome